# Parallel execution in robot framework (Threading)

Tags: python, robotframework, python-multithreading

**Example of the variables:**

1. UDIDs: [42439492, 3203201]
2. Platform versions: [8.0, 7,0]
3. Appium Ports: [4921, 4320]

**Current Issue**

I have 2 UDIDs so it will have 2 ports running. But currently it just keeps on creating new ports infinitely.

**Python Codes**

The following codes caused the appium server to keep on starting on a new port.

So the issue is that the code works when i just call the python scripts, but if i call it through robot framework, it does not end. So we figured out that robot framework might not be thread safe.

```
def run_tests_on_devices(udid):
    threads=[]    

for idx, device in enumerate(udid):

    cmd = "robot --variable PLATFORM_VERSION:" + str(get_platform_version_of_android_phone(device)) + " --variable DEVICE_UDID:" + str(device) + " --variable APPIUM_PORT:" + str(appiumInstances[idx]) + " android.robot"
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_command, args = (cmd,))
    t.daemon = True
    threads.append(t)


for x in threads:
    x.start()
    sleep(3)
    #Code is printing/working until here
for x in threads:
    x.join()
    #Does not reach until this stage. x.join() does not seem to be executed so the server kept on starting a new port.
```

**Suggested ways?**

1. Modify the code to perform parallel execution without using threading in python
2. I have been reading up on robot framework's process to see if i can do the equivalent in robot framework.
3. Pabot (It's a good tool but we prefer to just use python or robot framework)

Would appreciate if anyone can provide some insights or assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a look at pabot?

Comment: Why are you creating the threads as daemons? Such will be abruptly stopped midway when the main thread finishes, and you're salvaging that by calling `join()`. But in doing so, you are essentially killing the threading parallelism - the `join()` is blocking the execution within the called upon thread, all others are waiting for its completion.

Comment: Another thing catching my attention with the design - you're not doing anything to preserve the different threads' logs. Each one will output them (the output.xml, log and report htmls) in cwd. In the serial execution of demonized threads that'll be "OK" - each consecutive thread will rewrite them, and in doing so you'll get the logs for the last executed (only). But in actual parallelism the two threads will be writing to the same output.xml simultaneously, leading to garbled file in the best case, or corrupted in the worst; the outcome in any way is that you won't have execution logs.

Comment: By the way, `pabot` is not a solution for your use case :) It is designed to run in parallel a set of suites - A+B+C, to get ABC ran. While in your case, you want to run (in parallel) the same suite, with different arguments - A+A+A, getting AAA. So it's not applicable directly; you could reuse some its implementation though, it goes with subprocessing vs threads (which is better in most cases for multi-process machines with more RAM). Or, have the suite files duplicated and use as-is :)

Comment: Actually you can run same suite with different argumentfiles. —argumentfile1 .. —argumentfileN argsN.dat ..